# On click button sounds

Tags: android, button, click, effects, audio

I have looked through all visible threads on this, and I have tried to make it work, but it just doesn't.

All of the threads I have seen involve some sort of .raw file that I've never seen before... there was one thread that made a lot of sense, but when I followed what they did (i.e. copy+paste), it still didn't work.

Could you look at my code and tell me what the problem is? I'm sure this is a common problem a lot of people have: just adding SIMPLE on-click button sounds (like the built-in java ones). 
When I load up my emulator no sound plays onClick.

```
package com.example.attempt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SoundEffectConstants;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
     v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Audible Selection is enabled:

```
Settings -> Sounds & display -> Audible Selection
```

By the way, the `raw` you have seen in other threads is not a file. It is a special folder. If you create `res\raw` folder under your project root, you can access the files you have put there form your code using `R.res.raw`